# SVG not rendering when using react-native-svg-uri

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

### Environment info

React native info output:

```sh
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.4"
```

Library version: 1.2.3

### Steps To Reproduce

1. Create a fresh project using react-native-cli.
2. Bring in an SVG file into the `src` folder of the project (I downloaded and used the homer simpson image mentioned in the documentation of react-native-svg-uri for the test ).
3. Import the svg as `import MySVG from './mysvg.svg';`
4. Pass `MySVG` into `svgXmlData` property of `SvgUri` component

### Expected behaviour

The image should render on screen

### Reproducible sample code

```
import React from 'react';
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';

import MySVG from './mysvg.svg';

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
     <>
      <SvgUri
        svgXmlData={MySVG}
        width="25"
        height="25"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

### Error Message

[image: error message]

Comment: I have no idea how but after repeating the same thing over and over again it finally works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Direct Path Declaration

```js
<SvgUri
        width="25"
        height="25"
        source={require('./mysvg.svg')} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a svg file declared and not using an uri, I would recommend to use the react-native-svg project from the react-native-community (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg)

With this, you turn your svg file to a React Stateless Component (the translation is quite straightforward) and you can use it as a standard React component.